# UltraWinGrid - Get Current Cell/Column for a group by row

Tags: infragistics

I am trying to provide quick summary for the selected rows if the active cell is of type double or int. This works fine if the grid is not grouped by any column. But when grid is grouped by one or more columns, there is no active cell when top level rows are selected.

```
void ultraGrid_AfterSelectChange(object sender, AfterSelectChangeEventArgs e)
{
    var ultraGrid = ((UltraGrid)sender);

    var selected = ultraGrid.Selected;
    var hasCells = selected.Cells != null && selected.Cells.Count > 0;
    var hasRows = selected.Rows != null && selected.Rows.Count > 0;
    if ( !hasCells && !hasRows )
    {
        statusLabel.Text = string.Empty;
        return;
    }

    UltraGridColumn activeColumn;
    var activeCell = ultraGrid.ActiveCell;
    if( activeCell == null  )
    {
        var aUIElement = ultraGrid.DisplayLayout.UIElement.ElementFromPoint( ultraGrid.PointToClient(MousePosition));
        activeColumn = (UltraGridColumn)aUIElement.GetContext(typeof(UltraGridColumn));
    }
    else activeColumn = activeCell.Column;

    if( activeColumn == null || (activeColumn.DataType != typeof (double) && activeColumn.DataType != typeof (int) ) )
    {
        statusLabel.Text = string.Empty;
        return;
    }
    //code to calculate summaries for selected rows or cells and active column
}
```

But aUIElement.GetContext(typeof(UltraGridColumn)) always return null when group by rows are selected. 
How do I get active column / cell when group by rows are selected?

Comment: Thanks Rob. I tried to do the edit without adding my edit text at the end, but it said I had to add 6 non-space characters to complete the edit.

Answer (score 1):

If the column from the `GetContext` is null, make another `GetContext` call for the type `UltraGridGroupByRow`. If an instance is returned, get the `Column` property from it and that will give you the grouped column to which that row refers.